# Advice on postfix-to-infix parsers

Tags: c++, parsing, language-design

I've come across a proprietary stack-based scripting language that looks like a somewhat simplified version of x86 ASM.

I built a stack-based linear parser for this language in C++ that I hope will produce pseudo-C code to make the language a lot easier to read.

I've encountered at least one serious issue that I feel has to do with the linear nature of my parser... for example, let's say we have the following code:

```
push const int
push const str
call some_method
pop const str
pop const int
return last return val
```

With my current implementation, I could very easily generate the following:

```
retval = some_method(str, int)
return retval
```

But the following will be a major pain:

```
return some_method(some_str, some_int)
```

When I encounter an instruction/opcode, I will be aware of -variables- pushed onto the stack, but that is about it...

What it boils down to is that I can go from postfix to infix for a combination similar instructions (pushes + calls for example), but not for multiple ones.

I am very unexperienced when it comes to language parsers so go easy on me! What would be your suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is [symbolic execution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_execution). Arrange to have a C++ representation of expressions, such as

```
class Expression{...};
class StringConstant:public Expression{...};
class FunctionCall:public Expression{...};
```

Then, make your symbolic stack contain `Expression*`. When you then arrive at

```
return foo
```

compile this to

```
cout<<"return "; foo_expr->print();
```

where each Expression would have an appropriate (possibly recursive) print method.

**Edit**: If there is no return statement, you need to iterate over the value stack, and perform ->print for all values that haven't otherwise been consumed.

Comment: That's the thing, there is no guarantee there will be a return opcode. By advice I was thinking more along the lines of parsing techniques. I've read about building a hierarchical tree back-to-front etc that may solve my particular issue.

Comment: @Daniel: as for functions with no return statement - see my edit. As for "advice for parsing techniques" - I do believe that parsing techniques really won't help here. The issue you describe is clearly about the internal representation, not about the parsing.